# Optimize Google Places API Query for Prominent Parks, Mountains, Conservation Areas

Tags: google-places-api

First post on Stackoverflow.

I am using the Google API to sort images taken while traveling into organized folders, append tags and rename files with relevant information. I have my code working well but am not always happy with the results. I want to be able to focus my query results on major tourist attractions such as National Parks, Ski Resorts, Beaches, etc. The problem I am finding is that the prominence **"rankby"** variable and the **"radius"** are not giving satisfactory results. Here is a typical query for Zion National Park.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=37.269486111111,-112.948141666667&rankby=prominence&radius=50000&type=natural_feature,tourist_attraction,point_of_interest&keyword=&key=MYAPIKEY

The most prominent result is Springdale which is the town where you enter the part. Zion National Park is listed much further down in the results. What my code does is use the LAT and LON extracted using EXIF and does a Google API nearby search request to find the Place ID for where the photo was taken. It then does another API request for Place Details using the place_id provided by the previous step to cut down on the information I need to parse.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJ8R5RCzaNyoARegi3rqVkstk&fields=name,address_component&key=MYAPIKEY

I can force the nearby search to return a National Park by searching against "National Park" in the keywords variable but that limits my project to only being able to provide National Park results since the keywords field can only accept one string.

I would like a park of my query to be able to return the most prominent tourist attraction at the general level, i.e. Zion National Park, Yosemite National Park, etc. so I can sort images into the general name folders and another part of the query provides the exact location. i.e. I am on this trail or at this lookout. The problem is the Google API sees these specific locations "Trail, Lookout" as tourist attractions, parks, establishments, etc. as well so it chooses those first.

What I need help with is trying to figure out if there is a better way to structure my query to return the high-level / name of the major park.  From my understanding, the types field only searches on the first type even if there is more in the list and the keywords field can only accept one string as well making it impossible for one phase to capture all major destinations at a high level.

Perhaps it needs to be done with more queries but I am trying to limit the number of queries to stay inside the free quota. Maybe it will just take a long time to fully sort my files.

Read through and implemented Google API structure. I hoping someone can provide a more detailed query structure or method to parse out truly prominent locations rather than googles interpretation of prominence as it can be affected by user ratings, etc. It is not always accurate.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please provide more details regarding `truly prominent locations rather than googles interpretation of prominence as it can be affected by user ratings`? What was your basis that the google map's result is less accurate than what you said as accurate result? Is your basis of the "accurate result" have some kind of statistical evidence? or just a personal opinion of prominence for the said location? From what I can understand, user ratings would be a good basis of prominence already.

Comment: What I am finding with the results returned from the API is that user ratings doesn’t necessarily guarantee the the most general name for an area. If the user rating is high on a trail I hiked the most prominent result will likely be trial itself not the park I hiked inside. I am trying to figure out how I can return the prominent “major” park or area. Colloquial_area, locality,admin_levl etc. even return hyper accurate results instead of a more zoomed out result. I am using the API to sort images into generic folders for destinations instead of a million folders of trail blah, route blah.

Comment: I was hoping I could narrow my results down to what I think most would interpret as a prominent area. When I look for picture I am thinking I took that in Yosemite not I took that on Glacier Point trail. 

Trying to zoom out my results to a sub locality level but with most prominent destination if that makes sense. It may not be possible.

Comment: Yeah it may not be possible since the `prominence` value for `rankby` parameter is working as intended because it was designed to use the ratings of a POI as its basis for output. I would suggest that you try filing a feature request. Google engineers might try to consider this. You can do so in this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789309). This link came from here https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker.